# xaml slider customization with images

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Can anyone explain to me how to change the default thumb and track of a slider to use images?

I was able to change the slider background to use an image, but I cannot figure out how to change the thumb. But it tiles it.

any advice is appreciated.

This this works, but I can't move the slider or see the track:

```
<Slider Height="400" Width="60" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Slider.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider" >
                    <Thumb>
                        <Thumb.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/fader.png"/>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Thumb.Template>
                    </Thumb>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Slider.Template>
        </Slider>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Page.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="Slider">

        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyleVertical">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">

                                            <Rectangle Height="60" Width="30">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/fader.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            </Rectangle>

                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyleHorizontal">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">

                                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalThumbRect" Height="30" Width="60">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/fader2.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            </Rectangle>

                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid x:Name="SliderContainer" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">

                            <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                  Fill="DimGray"
                  Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                  <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="DimGray" Grid.Row="1" />
                  <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
              Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyleHorizontal}"
              DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Grid.Column="1"
              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect"
                  Fill="DimGray"
                  Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                  Fill="DimGray"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="2" />

                                <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"

              Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyleVertical}"
              DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete implementation but it will give a start.

```
 <Slider   Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Value="3">
        <Slider.Template>
            <ControlTemplate   TargetType="Slider" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton   Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb>
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50">
                                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="other.png"/>
                                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                                        </Ellipse>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton  Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Slider.Template>
    </Slider>
```

Comment: When I drop that code into my mainpage.xaml... it's all broken. Is there another place where I put this code?

Comment: NO, you have to use it on the main Page, without any other modification

Comment: track is undefined in UWP

Comment: Please give a solution for UWP.  Track is undefined in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **full working template for Windows 10 (UWP)**. Made minimum changes to customize `Thumb`. In this example `Thumb` is customized simply by `TextBlock`. Easy to customize by any other component.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomizedSlider" TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFill}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFill}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,0,-7,0" />
    <Setter Property="IsFocusEngagementEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyle">
                            <!-- WE DON'T NEED THIS-->
                            <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackground}" />-->
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <!-- WE DON'T NEED THIS-->
                                        <!--<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                            CornerRadius="4" />-->

                                        <!-- CUSTOMIZED THUMB WILL START HERE-->
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="&#xEA3B;" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Background}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="&#xEA3B;" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <!-- CUSTOMIZED THUMB WILL END HERE-->

                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusEngagementStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusDisengaged" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedHorizontal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedVertical">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                        x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForeground}"
                        Margin="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeMargin}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                        FontWeight="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <Grid x:Name="SliderContainer"
                        Background="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackground}"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                        <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" MinHeight="44">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="18" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="18" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="1" />
                            <TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Margin="0,0,0,4"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                            <TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderInlineTickBarFill}"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                            <!--<Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
                                Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                                DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                                Height="24"
                                Width="8"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                FocusVisualMargin="-14,-6,-14,-6"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />-->

                            <!-- HEIGHT AND WIDTH MUST SET TO AUTO -->
                            <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
                                Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                                DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                                Height="Auto"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                FocusVisualMargin="-14,-6,-14,-6"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" MinWidth="44" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="2" />
                            <TickBar x:Name="LeftTickBar"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                Margin="0,0,4,0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                            <TickBar x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderInlineTickBarFill}"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                            <TickBar x:Name="RightTickBar"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Margin="4,0,0,0"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                            <!--<Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"
                                Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                                DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                                Width="24"
                                Height="8"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                FocusVisualMargin="-6,-14,-6,-14"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />-->

                            <!-- HEIGHT AND WIDTH MUST SET TO AUTO -->
                            <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"
                                Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                                DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Height="Auto"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                FocusVisualMargin="-6,-14,-6,-14"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```